# Save Word Doc through Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, macos, ms-word

I am trying to open a word doc with excel VBA, Add some data from Excel and save as that document

this is my base code.
"

```
 Dim objWordDoc
    Set objWordDoc = objWordApp.Documents.Open(wordFileName)
    objWordApp.Visible = True


'other part of code

 objWordDoc.SaveAs fileName:=savePath
    'shutdown
   ' objWordDoc.Close
   ' If wordLaunched Then objWordApp.Quit
    Set objWordDoc = Nothing
    Set objWordApp = Nothing
```

this code is working fine in windows. and one of my friend was using it on Mac.
now He update Mac to new Beta version **macOS Sonoma 14 **
on there file is opened. data processed. but it was not save as the file
I have check it by stoping word file to close.
now I need to modify code so it should work on mac too

will this code work?
`objWordApp.activeDocument.SaveAs2 fileName:=savePath`

please give me a solution for it

> `objWordApp.activeDocument.SaveAs2 fileName:=savePath`

I tried this code for Mac. it works on windows. but I am not sure about mac

Comment: Mac has different file system. I guess you need to change `savePath`.

Comment: `savepath` is same as `wordFileName`

Comment: This is how I add value to **savepath**

` Dim savePath As String`
    `Dim actualFileName As String`
    
    `actualFileName = Mid(Mid(wordFileName, InStrRev(wordFileName, "/") + 1), InStrRev(wordFileName, "\") + 1)
    
    savePath = wordFileName
    savePath = Replace(savePath, actualFileName, "")
    savePath = savePath & templateSaveName & ".docx"`

Comment: It's difficult to say what's wrong w/o knowning your env. Check the value of `wordFileName, actualFileName, savePath` on Mac.